# TensorFlow lstm predicts the same class probability for every deferent example on test dataset

Tags: time-series, tensorflow, lstm

I am using tensorflow for time series classification. I am feeding fixed window timeseries to lstm cell and I am trying to classify if a timeserie belongs to class a or class b. After some training, I am testing the model to new time series that it has never been trained on. The problem is that the model predicts the same probability for every deferent time serie in the test dataset. It behaves like deferent timeseries are the same. Do you have any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: Can you share your code? The most likely explanation is that there is some issue in how the input is being processed.

Comment: I made an experiment to add to my test dataset a very deferent timeserie and the network was able distinguish this one. So probably the network is not sensitive enough or I need to do some preprocessing to the data in order to enlarge the differences between the examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might revise your pre-processing.

You train the LSTM on a certain set of training data. Now it learns the structure of this data. A time-series with different pre-processing isn't necessarily on the manifold that your other time-series were on. The reason for the odd predictions is related to [this](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/03/30/breaking-convnets/)